# Need to make a packaged app for Chrome using eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, html, google-chrome, gwt

I've been having a hard time trying to figure out how to create a packaged app using eclipse. I have the GWT plugin installed and I can make a web application. I looked at the tutorial and looked to see how to do that. Is there any way for me to convert that web app into a packaged app that has the .html, .css, the manifest, ect. If not, what plugins do I need to write a packaged app in eclipse. Thanks for the help

Comment: It looks like you might mean `JavaScript` not Java. Also, it might be you just have to create the specific packaged app files yourself and zip it up.

Comment: +1 . You need to elaborate and add details about what you are trying in your gwt app.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because I'm creating a device for a class and I want to create a packaged app so that the user can use the device even if they don't have internet. So from the sound of it, creating an app using the GWT will create an app that runs off a web server if I understand it correctly. Is there anyway I can extract the .json file from a project that was created using the GWT? If not, is there a good .json plugin for eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

**You can easily push a GWT app (with normal restrictions) as a Chrome extension.**

For a Start Read these -

Tutorial 1 - http://blog.tomtasche.at/2011/08/chromegwt-building-chrome-extensions.html

Tutorial 2 - http://tech-drum.blogspot.in/2012/06/building-chrome-extensions-with-gwt.html

You can also try and use this for reference - [gwt-chrome](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-chrome/)

Note - There is a [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5577) logged against GWT for making this process easy. "Star" it please.

Answer (score 0):

`The difference between a Packaged App and a Hosted App is the offline  behavior`

a Packaged App is an install able application on browser and an Web App is hosted from a web server and wont  offline.

But you are able to run the packaged  when the browser is offline with help of .json file ..hardly calling as manifest.json

[Helloworld Packaged App](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app.html)

[Chrome article on Packaged apps](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/apps.html)

Finally you need not  to use `Eclipse`  to create a packaged file because all of them are normal files (.html,.js,.css......).If you want use to browse the files easily and for better maintanace you can use it .
I